# SSRS Manual select entries from DB table to run report using a checkboxlist

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to create a report so that I can manually select which entries in a table to use for the report. I have not been able to find anything related to this topic over the past few days and am about to create a new table in the database and a web page that will allow me to select what I want to use, clear the new table and then copy over all of the selected rows then run the report.

So, can this be done in Report Builder 3.0 or should I just go with my potential solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was actually quite simple. I came across another report that did what I was looking for so I downloaded it and went into the properties for the parameters and noticed that the Allow multiple selections was checked. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use column/row visibility based on values from your parameter.